# Дан массив символов. Удалить часть текста, заключенного в скобки (вместе со скобками)

Tags: c++

Помогите составить алгоритм для решения задачи, исходную строку нужно изменить. Код хочу попробовать сам написать,

Comment: Если дело не в обучении, напрямую, а реализации, то посмотрите в сторону std::regex_replace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну грубо идея: идём по строке слева направо, поддерживаем 3 переменные - указатель на текущий символ (cur), указатель на записываемый символ (wrt) и количество открытых скобок (cnt).

Начальные значения cur = wrt = указатель на начало строки. cnt = 0.

```
Если текущий символ - открывающая скобка, то cnt++
Если количество открытых скобок равно 0, то мы пишем *cur в *wrt, wrt++
cur++
Если текущий символ - закрывающая скобка - то cnt--
Если *cur = 0 то выход.
Выполнить сначала.
```

Comment: Надо только учесть, что скобки могут и не совпадать - типа `aa(bb(cc(dd)ee`.

Comment: как я понимаю тогда нужно удалить в вашем случае (bb(cc(dd)

Comment: Это я оставил додумать автора вопроса, многое зависит от точной формулировки или доработок у преподавателя. Исправляется буквально 1 словом.

Answer (score 0):

Есть стандартные функции поиска подстроки в строке. Ищешь первую открывающую скобку и запоминаешь её индекс, затем тем же способом закрывающую и тоже запоминаешь индекс. То что между индексами так же можно получить стандартными функциями копирования подстройки начиная и заканчивая определенной позицией. Это и будет текст между скобками. Делайте с ним что хотите и повторяйте алгоритм. Так же для удобства можете использовать другую строку в которую будете складывать результат ваших действий . Я думаю . вариант с другим массивом лучший вариант . Иди по основному массиву и проверяй условия, то что удовлетворяет добавляй в другой массив

Comment: strchr — Возвращает указатель на первое вхождение младшего байта заданного параметра
strrchr — Возвращает указатель на последнее вхождение младшего байта заданного параметра в строке. Вы имели в виду эти функции?

Comment: я не сишник, я предложил  лишь алгоритм, а такие функции есть во всех языках, но называются по разному.

Answer (score 0):

Короче у меня не получилось изменить данную строку и я пошёл другим путём. Я копировал содержимое в другую строку, только есть, скажем так, один  большое вопрос. Если строка не содержит закрывающую скобку, то  у меня выводит мусор, точнее мусор после символа '('.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIAN");

    char str[100] = "# :#($ afe)0t:(rk: f)akt", *ptr;
    char n_str[100] = "\0", *n_ptr;     

    cout << "Данная строка: " << str << endl;

    ptr = str;

    while (*ptr) {      
        n_ptr = n_str;

        while (*ptr != '(' && *ptr) {
            *n_ptr = *ptr;
            n_ptr++; ptr++;

            //игнорируем символы которые стоят между скобок  
            //и сами скобки тоже игнорируем  
            if (*ptr == '(') {
                *ptr++;

                while (*ptr != ')')
                    ptr++;

                ptr++; //перемещаемся за за символ ')'
            }
        }
    }

    *n_ptr = '\0';
    cout << "Новая строка: " << n_str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Видимо вы не совсем поняли идею,  как это сделать в 1 строке. Вот http://ideone.com/mfD087 моя реализация.

Comment: Спасибо, за проделанный труд.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, если подразумевается удалять все законченные последовательности в скобках, то подходящим будет алгоритм, использующий стек для "распознавания" символов в скобках и "очередь", в которую помещаем пары индексов, соответствующих открывающей и парной ей закрывающей скобок.

Я пишу "очередь" в кавычках, поскольку, если индекс открывающей скобки в заносимой в "очередь" пары меньше индекса в ее конце, то "очередь" превращается в "стек" (с той стороны, куда обычно вставляют в нее элементы), т.е. новая пара индексов (на самом деле это только что закрывшаяся последовательность символов в скобках, которая началась ранее уже помещенной в очередь) замещает ранее помещенные в нее элементы.

Получаем такой алгоритм.

Просматриваем символы строки, при появлении открывающей скобки помещаем ее индекс в стек. Закрывающая скобка извлекает из стека индекс парной открывающей и они вместе образуют пару, которую надо поместить в очередь, учитывая замечание выше.

Т.е. в конце мы получаем массив ("очередь") пар индексов символов, которые д.б. удалены из строки. Реально удаление можно заменить пееписывание строки "по месту", исключая символы из пар в этом массиве.

(как всегда описание длиннее кода и пожалуй, непонятней -))

P.S.
@Ilya, Вы писали, что хотите написать код сами, если он все же будет интересен, черканите в комментарии (с указанием @avp (иначе я нотификацию не увижу (такова тут дурь))).

Comment: Спасибо за идею, но  до очереди и стэка я ещё не дошёл, пару месяцев читаю Шилдта

Comment: Ну, это просто. Стек (может быть реализован по разному), например  это массив в конец которого добавляем новые элементы и выбираем их оттуда же. Т.е. добавляем в a[0], a[1], a[2] потом достаем a[2], a[1] и в этот момент там остается a[0], если снова добавим, то положим в a[1]. А в очередь мы всегда добавляем в конец и всегда выбираем из начала. Т.е. клодем a[0], a[1], a[2], достаем a[0], a[1] ... Стек естественным образом реализуется в C++ контейнером std::vector, а поскольку "очередь" в Вашей задаче одноразовая, то тот же vector вполне подойдет.

Comment: @avp не уверен что здесь нужна очередь будет, а вот стек да, пригодится.

Comment: @pavel, я же написал "очередь". В том плане, что индексы ранее появившихся внешних (при условии, что они закрыты) скобок будут в ее начале. Собственно, в фазе удаления это логическая очередь удаляемых диапазонов символов. (нет, не умею я доходчиво описывать алгоритмы...)